# Coin in a jar trick

Tags: knowledge, lateral-thinking, magic

A jar with a single key inside has its lid closed shut. How can you get the key out? The jar is glued to the table, and the lid is stuck as well. Your solution should be quick (a minute max).

Comment: Where does the coin come in?

Comment: Is it coin or a key?

Comment: Hello @ Ayman Khalil. As you can see from the answers/comments you need to explain a few things. Coin or Key?  Can you do anything destructive like breaking or drilling? The wording needs help.

Comment: Did we get your answer? If not, I'll search for a new one.

Answer (score 8):

Classic topologist's answer:

> The universe is separated by the jar into two spaces. Declare the space with the key to be the outside, and the rest of the universe to be inside the jar.

Answer (score 8):

My answer:

> Jars are known to shatter when dropped from a certain height, which is probably why the OP included that the jar is glued to the table. The OP didn't say that the table is glued to the ground, so my guess is to lift the table upside-down, and drop it.

For those who would like a clearer example, here is a tutorial:

> [image]

Comment: Instructions unclear, got stuck in jar

Comment: Great diagram.  +1

Answer (score 5):

> Break the jar :-) If I really, really need that key out...